# I would like to find items that do not have any activity in the database

Tags: mysql

Step 1: Find all tables that have item_id column.

```
select * 
 from information_schema.columns 
 where table_schema = 'db.5' 
  and column_name like 'item_id';
```

Answer: 12 tables all with the item_id column

Step 2: How do I find other tables connected to the 12 tables and how do I eventually find the items that do not have activity in any of these tables?

Comment: Define an `activity`

Comment: If there are no documented foreign keys you need to do a manual inspection (look at each table) or read views and queries if there are any. I don't know about MySQL but Oracle and Microsoft allow to list dependencies, that might help to navigate the database.

Comment: In this case an activity is the item being a part of the table.  For example,  an item in the item table can be linked to Sales table via item_id.  This can further be linked to other tables aswel.

Comment: *"How do I find other tables connected to the 12 tables.."* - That's now something you should find. This is your database structure, you should *know* this. If someone else built it, maybe there is documentation, or -if you're lucky- at least some foreign keys. Whatever the case, this is something you do *before* writing a query. You don't search referencing tables on the fly.